# SQL if statement with unknown value

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, if-statement

I have a situation where I am supposed to be pulling a customer`s file from a database and returning their password if their file is found, but if the customer ID that was entered has not been found, I am to return "NOT FOUND."

I was trying to set it up as an if statement like this:
     if $customerID = anything
          return password;

However, I wasn't sure how exactly I would go about assigning "anything" as a real part of the code. Is there a way to do this, or should I reevaluate the way I`m going at this entirely?

Comment: Hmmm... What if an evil customer sets his password to `NOT FOUND.`?

Comment: which RDBMS are you using. Is this SQL Server or mySQL

Comment: Use a try catch block?  if it returns the password great, if not the catch block can output the message

Comment: please post what you have tried so far and we can try to help you figure it out

Comment: @w0lf - I hope no one is that mean!

@logixologist - I`m working in mySQL, sorry!

Comment: instead of hoping it won't happen you should eliminate that chance by returning something like `null` instead of a magic string

Comment: @SteveGreen I am in my first programming class with a not so fantastic teacher, and haven`t got a clue what that is. Can I use it in mySQL? Will do some searching.

@logixologist So far I haven`t tried anything, because I wanted to figure out if it was possible to set the value for the customers password to "anything" before I tried something else.

Thank you for the replies!(:

Comment: @w0lf Again, this is my first class and both of those things mean nothing to me, unfortunately. I wish I had a better background to this so I wasn`t so naive. In addition, this is an assignment I am working on, so that may be very helpful to me in the future, but for now, I don`t think my professor will be quite that mean!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) to do something like this, but really, it's better to detect the NULL in your code and deal with the 'no user' condition.

```
SELECT IFNULL(password, 'NOT FOUND') AS password 
FROM yourtable 
WHERE customerid=XXX;
```

The problem, as others have noted, is that you can't tell the difference between a missing user record, and one with 'NOT FOUND' as the password. The implications of this *might* be benign, but also might lead to an exploitable condition in future. When it comes to check user inputs, trust nothing :)

Comment: This solution falls down if I set my password to `NOT FOUND` :)

Comment: That's a flaw in the OP's request, not the solution :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice why would the OP store passwords in plain text anyway?!

Comment: Thank you for your help! Like I said above, I should hope in this situation my professor wouldn`t be mean enough to put me in that situation :P Should I use this solution, since I don`t have a customer ID, could I just plus $customerID into the "XXX"?

Comment: @FabianBigler, why would you return "NOT FOUND" as the password at all?  Why not just return `NULL`? :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice Yes, that's hilarious. But it's also hilarious to store passwords in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in SQL, by using a subquery and `coalesce()`.  The following is a guess at your data structure, but it shows how you can return `NOT FOUND` when nothing is found:

```
select coalesce((select f.password
                 from files f
                 where f.customerId = $CustomerId
                ), 'NOT FOUND')
```

Note:  This assumes that at most one file has a given customer id.  If not, it will return an error, something like "subquery returns more than one value".

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am completely unfamiliar with using coalesce, though I am intrigued. I am being graded in goBONGO, and it is very picky, so since I have not learned it, it will most likely not be accepted. However, you gave me something to think and learn about- which is better than the solution itself (: